# Optimize this linear transformation for images with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, transformation

Good evening,

I'm trying to learn NumPy and have written a simple Linear transformation that applies to an image using for loops:

```py
import numpy as np

M = np.array([
    [width, 0],
    [0, height]
])

T = np.array([
    [1, 3],
    [0, 1]
])

def transform_image(M, T):
    T_rel_M = abs(M @ T)
    new_img = np.zeros(T_rel_M.sum(axis=1).astype("int")).T
    
    for i in range(0, 440):
        for j in range(0, 440):
            x = np.array([j, i])
            coords = (T @ x)
            x = coords[0]
            y = coords[1]
            new_img[y, -x] = image[i, -j]
    
    return new_img

plt.imshow(transform_image(M, T))
```

It does what I want and spits out a transformation that is correct, except that I think there is a way to do this without the loops.

I tried doing some stuff with meshgrid but I couldn't figure out how to get the pixels from the image in the same way I do it in the loop (using i and j). I think I figured out how to apply the transformation but then getting the pixels from the image in the correct spots wouldn't work.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
Great help with below solutions, lezaf's solution was very similar to what I tried before, the only step missing that I couldn't figure out was assigning the pixels from the old to the new image. I made some changes to the code to exclude transposing, and also added a astype("int") so it works with float values in the T matrix:

```py
def transform_image(M, T):
    T_rel_M = abs(M @ T)
    new_img = np.zeros(T_rel_M.sum(axis=1).astype("int")).T
    x_combs = np.array(np.meshgrid(np.arange(width), np.arange(height))).reshape(2,-1)
    coords = (T @ x_combs).astype("int")
    new_img[coords[1, :], -coords[0, :]] = image[x_combs[1, :], -x_combs[0, :]]
    
    return new_img
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more efficient solution is the following:

```
def transform_image(M, T):
    T_rel_M = abs(M @ T)
    new_img = np.zeros(T_rel_M.sum(axis=1).astype("int")).T

    # This one replaces the double for-loop
    x_combs = np.array(np.meshgrid(np.arange(440), np.arange(440))).T.reshape(-1,2)
    # Calculate the new coordinates
    coords = (T@x_combs.T)
    # Apply changes to new_img
    new_img[coords[1, :], -coords[0, :]] = image[x_combs[:, 1], -x_combs[:,0]]
```

I **updated** my solution removing the for-loop, so now is a lot more straightforward.

After this change, the time of the *optimized* code is `50 ms` compared to the initial `3.06 s` of the code in question.

Comment: Thank you, this was more or less exactly what I was looking for and trying to do. NumPy functionalities just feel so strange to me coming from other languages, but at the same time clever! I want to think in for loops but hopefully I'll learn in time!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to have some confusions between width/height, x/y, ... so not 100% my code won't need adaptation. But I think, the main idea is the one you are looking for

```py
def transform_image(M, T):
    T_rel_M = abs(M @ T)
    j,i=np.meshgrid(range(width), range(height))
    ji=np.array((j.flatten(), i.flatten()))
    coords = (T@ji).astype(int)
    new_img=np.zeros((coords[1].max()+1, coords[0].max()+1), dtype=np.uint8)
    new_img[coords[1], coords[0]] = image.flatten()
```

The main idea here is to build a set of coordinates of the input image with meshgrid. I don't want a 2d-array of coordinates. Just a list of coordinates (a list of pairs i,j). Hence the flatten. So `ji` is a huge 2×N array, N being the number of pixels (so width×height).
`coords` is the transformation of all those coordinates.
Since your original code seemed to have some inconsistency with size (the rotated image did not fit in the `new_img`), I choose the easy way to compute the size of `new_img`, and just compute the max of those coordinates (a bit overkill: the max of the four corners would be enough)

And then, I use this set of coordinates as indexes for `new_img`,  to which I affect the matching image, that is `image` flatten

So, no for loop at all.

(Note that I've dropped the -x thing also. Just because I struggled to understand. I could have putted it back now that I have a working solution. But I am not 100% sure if it wasn't there because you also tried/errored some strange adjustment. But anyway, I think what you were looking for is how to use meshgrid to create a set of coordinates and process them without loop. Even if you may need to adapt my solution, you have it: flatten the coordinates of meshgrid, transform them with a matrix multiplication, and use them as index for places of all pixels of the original image)

### Edit : variant

```py
def transform_image(M, T):
    T_rel_M = abs(M @ T)
    ji=np.array(np.meshgrid(range(width), range(height)))
    coords = np.einsum('ik,kjl', T, ji).astype(int)
    new_img=np.zeros((max(coords[1,0,-1],coords[1,-1,0], coords[1,-1,-1])+1, max(coords[0,0,-1], coords[0,-1,0], coords[0,-1,-1])+1), dtype=np.uint8)
    new_img[coords[1].flatten(), coords[0].flatten()] = image.flatten()    
    return new_img
```

The idea is the same. But instead of flattening directly `ji` original coordinates, I keep them as is. Then use `einsum` to perform a matrix multiplication on a 3D array (which returns also a 2d 2×width×height arrays, whose each `[:,j,i]` value is just the transformation of `[j,i]`. So, it is just the same as previous `@`, except that it works even if, instead of having a 2×N set of coordinates we have a 2×width×height one).
Which has 2 advantages

- Apparently it is sensibly faster to create ji than way
- It allows the usage of just corners to find the size of the new image, as I've mentioned before (that was more difficult when `coords` was flatten from its creation).

### Timing

| Solution | Timing |
| --- | --- |
| Yours | 4.5 s |
| lezaf's | 3.2 s |
| This one | 49 ms |
| The variant | 41 ms |

Comment: Thank you for your example, it's very valuable for me as a NumPy beginner and hopefully for other's with a similar problem.